# UV surface color via scripting?

Tags: scripting, uv

I'm trying to make a parametric surface where the color depends on its coordinates.
Something like this figure

[image]

The biggest constrain that I have is the color function is quite complicated, so it has to go into a python script (and basically all tutorials are done through the graphic interface of blender)

Comment: I would use parametric equations using geometry nodes with shader nodes.  https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/305963/solving-mathematical-xyz-equations-in-geometry-nodes

Comment: Another one would be https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/212723/changing-the-angle-curvature-of-a-mesh-created-using-python-and-parametric-e